# Backpropagation demo

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, curve, backpropagation, demo

i have managed to implement my own *backpropagation* algorithm. I was able to train my neural network to resolve OR/AND/XOR problems so far. I am using a sigmoid function. For my school project I am looking for an idea of simple graphical demonstration of this algorithm. I need something simple but effective.

My idea is to implement a demo where i can place points into cartesian plane and then separate them by curve.
For linearly separable problems, perceptron weights could be used as a vector to find line which separates the points (*Two dimensions = 3 inputs = 3 weights, one is 1*). For example in 2D:

```
w2*x2 + w1*x1 + w0*1 = 0
```

- How can i find the curve polynom that separates the points (2D) (*so i can
  also separate linearly inseparable points solvable by BP*)?
- Or is there
  easier way to demonstrate it's functionality?

[image: Curve]

Thank you.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://tjo-en.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/06/234155

Comment: Sorry, but this article does not contain anything about math behind drawing the curves.

Comment: You asked about a way to present the problem. The rest is a bit vague. Are you trying to make a contrast between single and multi-layer perceptrons? For multiple layers and non-linearity the equation becomes nested as in  z = f(sum(w y)) = f(sum(w f(w x))). Since sigmoid(0)=0.5, your decision boundary is thus all the points x that lead to z = 0. Maybe [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15381-s07/www/slides/042407neuralNetworks.pdf) helps (around slide 27).

Comment: Oh thank you! I see it now, so in multilayer NN the curve(respectively the function which decides where the point goes to) is a composition of activation functions right? (sigmoids in my case). Sorry for vagueness, english is not my native language :(.

Comment: Pretty much, or to be a bit more precise the composition is of the layers in which the activations take place. No need to be sorry!